# How to assign a value to pointer object c++

Tags: c++, pointers, dev-c++

I'm new here and I wish that you can resolve this question, it is a constant error or omission on my programs when I use a data type char on referentiation in objects derived of struct's or classes. This is my source.
Thanks in advance.

```
 struct test{
    public:

        char cadena[20];
        int num;

   }objeto;

  int main(){

    test *POJ = &objeto;
    (*POJ).cadena="Hello Guys";
    POJ->num=23;
    cout<<(*POJ).cadena<<", "<<POJ->num;

  }
```

Comment: You need `strcpy()`. After all I'd recommend using `std::string`.

Comment: The more common syntax for `(*POJ).cadena` is `POJ->cadena`. You cannot assign a `char *` to a `char []` like that. Use `std::string` instead, it has proper overloads to make that work. It will probably be easier to [read a book](http://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/3484570) instead of asking here.

Answer (score 7):

```
(*POJ).cadena="Hello Guys";
```

`cadena` is an array. An array cannot be assigned to.

Either make `cadena` a `std::string`, which is what all self-respecting C++ code will use to store text string, or use the C `strcpy()` function to copy raw character data into a plain `char` array.